# Property does not exist on type JQueryStatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, typescript, typescript2.0

I have written a jQuery plugin where I use jQuery's internal _data method.
Which leads to the above compiler error.

```
(function ($) {     

var evts = $._data(document, 'events'); // internal method
....
```

Can I supress this error and how?
What is the recommended way to approach this issue?

I know I could do the following:

```
$["_data"]
```

or

```
($ as any)._data
```

but I would prefer making a `$._data` a valid method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but I would prefer making a $._data a valid method call.

The types intentionally don't allow internal API calls as *the jquery team doesn't want you to use these methods*. If you want to write unsafe code like this you are free to use `$ as any` as you have figured out.

If you want such unsafe access to be done safely you can extend the [`JQuery` interface with new functionality](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/jquery.html)

```
interface JQuery {
  _data: any; // Replace with your types
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
declare var $: any;
```